# What is the fastest horse in Mount and Blade Warband?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I really enjoy the whole Riders of Rohan effect of leading my all-cavalry force in a thunderous charge against the scurrilous Nords. However, I don't like getting all bunched up: I want to be out in front making a huge spectacle of myself, not back in the pack. What is the absolute fastest horse in the game?

Note: I already have a heavily armored horse for fights when that's a better option than speed (I carry it around in my bag, I guess...).

Comment: The fastest horse-type in the game is the Courser, but it has very little in the way of durability. Modifiers that boost speed I believe are Champion and Spirited, of the two I think Spirited is a larger boost, but I can't quite recall. I'll check when I get home if you don't have an answer by then.

Comment: If you cannot find a fast enough horse to run faster than your allies, call the cavalry group (Default button: 3) and press F1 for movement commands, then F2 to have them follow you. They will stay as close to you as possible but always 10 steps behind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Courser is the fastest horse type in the game, with a base speed stat of 50. A horse with the Champion variant grants +4 speed, and a horse with the Spirited variant grants +2 speed.

This means that a Champion Courser combines for a blistering 54 speed, whereas the standard Warhorse has a speed of 40.

[Source](http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Horses)

Answer (score 2):

As said already, Courser is technically the fastest, but using a Courser is very risky due to very low HP, especially if you face the nords with their throwing axes -- one hit in the head at its full speed, and you are not on horseback anymore, and your Courser is likely no more Champion (crippled). So you should probably go for increasing Riding skill if you really want to be fast. If you want more speed than the armoured horse (Charger, War Horse), you should probably try Hunter -- it's relatively fast compared to armoured horse and also relatively tough compared to Courser.